# Is there a way to detect cancelled download?

Tags: browser, spring-mvc, download

Let's say I have a Spring MVC web application and it allows users to download a file. An email is sent at the same time as the file is sent to the user.

Is there a way to detect cancelled download so I could send the email only if the download has been successful?

Comment: @pepez: Once you got it working, please post an answer with some example sourcecode (feel free to accept it as the best answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a download script that serves larger files in seperate blocks. When the last block has been served, you can **assume** (there is no way to **know** with HTTP) that the complete file was received by the client.

Have a look at questions [157318](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318) and [194579](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194579/) on how to achieve this in PHP. Since you always use HTTP (or HTTPS) to serve the files, the same principles apply to your question.