# Pause-able download for Apache

Tags: php, apache, web-applications, download

I have an Apache server running which hosts a php web application. This server also provides provisions for downloading a file size of around 900MB from it. However, while testing the application I found out that it's not possible to pause the downloads and resume them later on.

Could someone help me? Is it an apache property I must change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you serve your files with `php` then you should implement `Range` header processing in your script. You can recieve current range value from `$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']`. It contains the offset in bytes from begin of file.

ps: as usually mentioned - almost everything is already answered here ;-) [Resumable downloads when using PHP to send the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file/157447#157447)