# Videos not playing on iPhone when using JW Player plugin

Tags: mobile, video, iphone, jwplayer

In creating a mobile version of a site, I'm running into problems with the video not playing on the iPhone. I'm using the JW Player plugin and believe it has something to do with range request headers. My hosting company enabled range request headers but after it still wasn't working, they noticed that the videos were being passed via PHP so the apache header modifications had no affect.

I saw this question: [Using php to output an mp4 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924061/using-php-to-output-an-mp4-video), but I'm not sure how implement that within WordPress.

Has anyone else been able to get videos working on an iPhone browser using the JW Player plugin?