# View an mp4 video through JWPlayer on Android device delivered using php

Tags: php, android, mobile, jwplayer

This has had me stumped for days. I am trying to get an mp4 video to play through JWPlayer when viewing on an Android mobile phone and using php to deliver the file.

So far I have established that the mp4 does work when I hand JWPlayer a direct link to the file, but not when I try to use fread in php. Although if I view the video on my PC when using the same fread function, it works. So the mp4 is fine for mobile and PC, the fread function is only fine for PC. What could be stopping this from working?

I have tried the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924061/using-php-to-output-an-mp4-video) and even adding the suggested 'session_write_close()' mentioned in the comments, no go on mobile, fine on PC. I used the function at Mobiforge pointed to at Answer 2 of the same question, again works on PC not on mobile. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was an error being thrown in the script that stopped the request being completed. Everything works now, thanks.