# Load Video with PHP

Tags: php, video, load

I am trying to load a video file in php using by selecting the file with _GET.

Here is the code

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET["id"];
$video = "vid" . $id . ".mp4";
if (isset($_GET["id"]) AND $_GET["id"] == $id) {
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
print file_get_contents($video);
} 
else {
echo "File not found.";
}
?>
```

This is my web link.
http://www.animesour.com/video.php?id=555 This will get the file vid555.mp4 
However, when you visit the link it doesn't load the video or play it.
It will load images fine, but doesn't seem to work when it's video.

Basically I need it so that when I link http://www.animesour.com/video.php?id=555 in an I frame, that it will load the video. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should ouput a video tag with the file as the source.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797762/reading-mp4-files-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $video = "{URL TO VIDEO BASED ON $id}";
    echo "<video controls><source src='{$video}' type='video/mp4'></video>";

} else {
    echo "File not found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: isset($_GET["id"]) function need to be checked before retrieving the id value from parameter. Otherwise if id field is not exist in URL it'll throw error

Comment: @Sundar You're right, I didn't see that error in the original code. I've updated my code. Thanks!

Comment: @Veloncia Because there were unescaped double quotes within the double quotes. I have updated the answer to use single quotes.