# Masking/redirecting a video URL via PHP

Tags: php, html, video, flowplayer, embedding

I'm desperately (hours of research and no luck so far) trying to create a PHP page which can be used as a path for video embedding. I'm doing this so that I can give out a path to 3rd parties, that they can use for embedding, which won't change, even if I have to host the video elsewhere.

I've tried using the code referenced here...
[Reading mp4 files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797762/reading-mp4-files-with-php/15798140#15798140)

... but it doesn't work at all for me.

The video files will be hosted on a CDN and 3rd parties will need fixed links that they can embed on their own sites like:

```
    <div data-swf="$resourcePath/resources/flowplayer.commercial-5.4.3/flowplayer.swf" class="flowplayer is-splash play-button" data-ratio="0.5625">
        <video>
            <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.mycdndomain.com/embed/loader.php?v=1"/>
        </video>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.
-Josh

Comment: Note that if I use a hard-coded path in src="" it works fine. What I see when it doesn't work is a Quicktime logo with ?.

Comment: you don't need to use PHP to load and push the file, why not just use a redirect to the real video (send a 301 or 302 redirect)