# Encrypt url amazon s3 with php

Tags: php, encryption, amazon-s3, mp4

I want to protect my url .mp4 amazon s3 to be able to insert it in my player on my site. I would like to get one thing:

```
https://[mysite]/encrypt/encriptar.php?v=M3BtRGtUNkRoSndYRU5PdWI0Tmd2SjUrUmZRWWxybFVGU2pCTHBkT3B0U1Fkd3JsN2RaQXFQYURYdjVUL1g2bk1KQTkvcUZKbUY3UTRvOVNSNzNtbks3NUl6TzlZVFdHbXFKT1ZQUVNvOU9ndS9CTnowYmVqVWk4dXA4dzk0L0xVOStlb1Y5UTFsaU1RTmVKUUFUd2VRPT0=
```

I found this script but it does not seem to work, it does not play the video:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $sid = session_id();

    $path = "http://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my bucket/myfile.mp4";

    $hash = md5($path.$sid);

    $_SESSION[$hash] = $path;

    ?>

    <html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="encriptar.php?video=<?= $hash ?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `encriptar.php` do?

Comment: do this
[link]<?php
    session_start();
    $sid = session_id();

    $path = "http://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my bucket/myfile.mp4";

    $hash = md5($path.$sid);

    $_SESSION[$hash] = $path;

    ?>[/link]

Comment: Md5 is not an encryption

Answer (score 1):

When someone visits that page they will try to play the video by visiting that page again. It's a cycle.

Do this in `encriptar.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
$sid = session_id();

$path = "http://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my bucket/myfile.mp4";

$hash = md5($path.$sid); //You need to use proper encryption. This is not secure at all.

$_SESSION[$hash] = $path;
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="decrypt.php?video=<?= $hash ?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</body>
</html>
```

This should be your `decrypt.php`

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_GET["video"]) && isset($_SESSION[$_GET["video"]])) {
   header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
   $file = $_SESSION[$_GET["video"]]; //Get the filename
   readfile($file); //Proxy
   die();       

}
```

This way your encryptar is creating a hash to a decryption script that will decrypt and proxy the file. Note that everyone can still download the video, the only thing this protects you against is people figuring out your bucket name.

Comment: i tried as you said i see this <source src = "decrypt.php? video = ccff2bd199ed19ba225b2dd243dd6e42" type = "video / mp4"> but the file does not play appears invalid source why?

Comment: OK the video works, but if I move the player forward
half video example video hangs
to forward and back the player I have to wait for all the buffering to be full.
without script the video works perfectly.
  you have a solution for this
  thank you so much

Comment: @evil1990 that's much more complex. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797762/reading-mp4-files-with-php