# Prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded with PHP

Tags: php, html5-video, session-cookies, readfile

This code prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded and only display video.

It works great in Firefox browser but it does not work in Chrome and Safari browsers! Does anyone knows the problem?

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies',1);
session_start();

$mp4 = uniqid(); 
$_SESSION[$mp4]='a.mp4';
echo '<video autoplay="autoplay">'
    .'<source src="video.php?video='.$mp4.' type="video/mp4">'
    .'</video>';
?>
```

video.php

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies',1);
session_start();
$file='myhiddenvideos/'.$_SESSION[$_GET['video']];
$_SESSION=array();
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(),'', time()-42000,$params["path"],$params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
if(!file_exists($file) or $file==='' or !is_readable($file)){
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 File not found',true);
  exit;
  }
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: try to change the header of the PHP http://stackoverflow.com/a/15798799/5154084

Comment: @FahedAlkaabi This is a little confusing. No other easy way?

Comment: Does the videos always MP4 ?

Comment: @FahedAlkaabi : Yes.

Comment: take a look at this article - someone else was trying to do the same thing more or less. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved?rq=1

Comment: @RamRaider: I read this page thanks.

Comment: You will note then the comment / answer by @Starx near the bottom, simply stating "You can't"