# how to add videos on our website which can be accessed by specific users only

Tags: php, video, web

> > I am currently building my website. I have some videos which I want to let
> >     visible only to some specific users after some authentication.I want like videos will be available on website but it should be played only after some process to specific people only.How can I put it?I would be grateful if someone helps me with whole process.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: First of all keep a registration in your website where people can register.While login check if the user is registered or not if he is registered then keep session id of that registered user.And show the videos to all registered people by checking session id.

Comment: make a function which checks whether the user is authenticated

Comment: You might want to consider reading the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) docs.

Answer (score -1):

There are some ways to do it. First you need to make pages which play video safe by adding some authentication requirement to them and in addition you need to secure your video file safe from direct accessing. 
I can say if you use PHP you may create some virtual files which points to real file location and make them safe as you need. In PHP you can create some virtual files to deliver video files by adding appropriate header.
Refer to this page for more information:
[Using php to output an mp4 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924061/using-php-to-output-an-mp4-video)