# How to run plugin / library when changing video?

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

When executing the code the `videoJS` **plugin** replaces the `HTML5` video player, and really happy, I said between me what I achieved.

But when clicking on the next video, even when returning to the first video, the **plugin** is lost, leaving me the default player of `HTML5`

You can check it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhostingfree/maj0g36k/2/) or here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function insertar_contenido(vid, elemento) {

    var contenido, fuente
    var url = elemento.attr("href")
    var ext = "mp4"
    var formato = ext
    var es_video = new RegExp("^.+\\." + ext + "$").test(url)
    var cargando = $('.loading')

    function mostrar() {
      cargando.fadeIn(200)
    }

    function ocultar() {
      cargando.fadeOut(100)
    }
    mostrar()
    var cuadro = vid.find(".cuadro")
    if (cuadro.length != 0) {
      $("#ocultado").append(cuadro)
    }
    if (es_video) {
     var json = {"aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2]};
     contenido = $(document.createElement("video"))
     fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
     fuente.attr("src", url)
     fuente.attr("type", "video/" + formato)
     contenido.attr("controls", true)
     contenido.attr("autoplay", true)
     contenido.attr("class","video-js")
     contenido.attr('data-setup', JSON.stringify(json));
     contenido.on('waiting', mostrar)
     contenido.on('canplay', ocultar)
     contenido.append(fuente)
    } else {
      var id = elemento.attr("id")
      if (id == undefined) {
        contenido = $(document.createElement("iframe"))
        contenido.attr("src", url)
        contenido.on('load', ocultar)
      } else {
        contenido = $(document.createElement("div"))
        contenido.append($("#c_" + id))
        ocultar()
      }
    }
    vid.html("")
    vid.append(contenido)
    $("#enlaces a").removeClass("playing")
    elemento.addClass("playing")
  }

  var indice = 0
  var vid = $('#myvid')
  var primer_elemento = $("#enlaces a:first")
  var enlaces = $("#enlaces a").map((x, y) => {
    return {
      a: x,
      b: y
    }
  })

  insertar_contenido(vid, primer_elemento)
  primer_elemento.addClass("playing")

  $("#enlaces a.link").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var esto = $(this)

    indice = enlaces.filter((x, y) => y.b == this)[0].a

    insertar_contenido(vid, esto)
  })
  $("#atras").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var esto = $(this)
      --indice
    if (indice < 0) {
      indice += enlaces.length
    }
    enlaces[indice].b.click()
  })
  $("#siguiente").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var esto = $(this)
      ++indice
    if (indice >= enlaces.length) {
      indice -= enlaces.length
    }
    enlaces[indice].b.click()
  })
})
```

```css
#myvid {
  color: #ffff;
}

.container * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container *::after,
.container *::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #A97A7A;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  background: #010101;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 550px;
}

.vidcontainer {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.videolist {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.vids {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #292626;
  max-height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #616060;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  list-style: none;
  direction: rtl;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #8A8A8A;
  border: 1px solid #AFACAC;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #FF8D00;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vids a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* --- controllers --- */

.controllers {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.controllers button {
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #777;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.controllers button:focus {
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
  border-color: #ff8d00;
  color: #ff8d00;
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.btnPlay::after {
  content: "\f04b";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.paused::after {
  content: "\f04c";
}

.sound::after {
  content: "\f027";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.sound2:after {
  content: "\f028";
}

.muted::after {
  content: "\f026";
}

.btnFS::after {
  content: "\f065";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.ads {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #777;
  top: 27.5px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.bigplay {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 127.5px;
  left: 85px;
  z-index: 11;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}

.closeme {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px!important;
  color: #ff8d00;
  font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
  background-color: #999;
  border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  -o-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

.playing:after {
  content: "\f01d";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #ff8d00;
  float: left;
}


/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */

.topControl {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Progress bar */

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #999;
}

.progress span {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.timeBar {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 0;
  background: #ff8d00;
}

.bufferBar {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 0;
  background: #eee;
}


/* time and duration */

.time {
  width: 12%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
  right: -12%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.topControl:hover .time {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.topControl:hover .progress {
  width: 88%;
  height: 12px;
}


/* VOLUME BAR CSS
        volume bar */

.volume {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: #999;
}

.volumeBar {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ff8d00;
  z-index: 10;
}

.loading {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
  top: 172.5px;
  left: 330px;
  position: absolute;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}

ul.speedcnt {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  -o-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

ul.speedcnt li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'verdana', tahoma, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.speedcnt li.selected {
  background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5-unsafe/video-js.css">-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5-unsafe/video.js"></script>-->

<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="vidcontainer">
    <div id="myvid"></div>
    <div class="loading">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="videolist">
    <nav class="vids">
      <a id="atras" href="#">Back</a>
      <a id="siguiente" href="#">Next</a>
    </nav>
    <nav id="enlaces" class="vids">
      <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test1</a>
      Y<a clases="link" href="https://www.wikipedia.org">test web</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test2</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4">test3</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/dw11222.mp4">test4</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4">test5</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="ocultado" style="display: none">
      <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_10">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js'></script>
```

I thought that the `videoJS` **plugin** `videoJS` not work for several videos on the same page, but really if it works for several videos here the test: https://jsfiddle.net/bq81phfy/

So what I can think of is that a possible solution is to run the `videoJS` **plugin** at the same time by switching to the next video or going back to the previous video.

My problem: How do I get the plugin's libraries to run? O How to make the **plugin** work for all videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Revised answer)*

For the full code and demo, you can check my Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tqouhnbc/).

And my approach is as follows:

- Only one `video` element for all the video links.
- When displaying a non-video content, the `video` is hidden.
- When displaying a video, the non-video content are removed.

And you can see what I changed/added from below code:

**(The `...` means your code, nothing changed there.)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function insertar_contenido(vid, elemento) {

    ...

    contenido = vid.find('video:first');
    var videojs = contenido.closest('.video-js');
    var exists = videojs.length >= 1;

    if (es_video) {
      if (exists) {
        vid.children('.non-video').remove();
        videojs.show();

        fuente = contenido.children('source');
        fuente.attr('src', url);
        fuente.attr('type', 'video/' + formato);

        contenido.attr('src', url);
        contenido.get(0).load();
      } else {
        ...

        vid.html('');
        vid.append(contenido);
      }
    } else {
      if (exists) {
        videojs.hide();
      }

      ...

      contenido.addClass('non-video');
      vid.append(contenido);
    }
    ...
  }

  ...
});
```

### UPDATE

Actually, for inline content, the element should be initially hidden:

```html
<div id="c_inline-1" style="display: none">
  <h3>Inline Content</h3>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>
```

And for that, I changed the `contenido.append($("#c_" + id))` to:

```
contenido.append($("#c_" + id).html())
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a6ugk9ho/).

### UPDATE 2

Alternatively, if you'd rather use a new `video` element for each video, then just [call `videojs()`](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html#manual-setup) on the created `video` element. Just add these lines *after* the `vid.append(contenido)` in your [original code](https://jsfiddle.net/mhostingfree/maj0g36k/2/):

```
if (es_video) {
  videojs(contenido.get(0));
}
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3w1L5afm/).

### UPDATE 3

I added this:

```
// If clicking on the same link, do nothing.
if (vid.data('elemento') === elemento.get(0)) {
  return;
}
vid.data('elemento', elemento.get(0));
```

and this:

```
// .non-video are always re-created.
vid.children('.non-video').remove();
```

to the `insertar_contenido()` function, which should fix this issue: "*Click several times on the title of the listing `iFrame` and `Inline`. And the same content is doubling the same number of times you click*".

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4kx3hnfw/1/).