# Handling byte-range requests with cURL

Tags: php, iphone, ios, video, curl

I am currently trying to stream a video to an iPhone. My situation is almost identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128906/mp4-plays-when-accessed-directly-but-not-when-read-through-php-on-ios) question, just a bit more specific. The video I am retrieving comes from a different website, so I cannot change how the videos are retrieved.

I currently have to post some data to a URL, and I will get a video back (if all the data is valid). I currently just grab the data using cURL, echo it out, and set the header to `video/mp4`. This works fine in most cases, but like the other question - it won't work for iPhones. I looked it up, and obviously came across that.

Now, this would be fine if I were simply reading a file from a server, but unfortunately, that's not that case since I have to post specific data to the server to actually retrieve the video.

How would I go about handling byte-range requests with cURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by simply downloading the video from the external source (the whole thing), opening a stream on that data, and then printing out the requested bytes from the byte range request. To do this, I modified the answer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16419103/877651), so it would just open a stream based on the data I downloaded:

```
function rangeDownload($file)
{
    $fp = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    fwrite($fp, $file);
    rewind($fp);

    $size = strlen($file);
    $length = $size;
    $start = 0;
    $end = $size - 1;
    header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        $c_start = $start;
        $c_end = $end;
        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false)
        {            
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }

        if ($range == '-')
            $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
        else
        {

            $range = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];
            $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size)
        {

            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }
        $start = $c_start;
        $end = $c_end;
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
        fseek($fp, $start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    }
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    header("Content-Length: $length");

    $buffer = 1024 * 8;
    while (!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end)
    {    
        if ($p + $buffer > $end)
            $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
        set_time_limit(0);
        echo fread($fp, $buffer);
        flush();
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

This code is assuming that the argument passed to `rangeDownload` is a string of data. This is an example of usage:

```
// curl initialization here...
$result = curl_exec($ch);
rangeDownload($result);
```

The `rangeDownload` will handle echoing the data out, and parsing the HTTP Range. This method is not the best, but I discovered that my external host didn't support byte range requests, so I couldn't have done it a better way (besides maybe caching). I would not use this method unless you cannot control whether or not the place you are downloading data from handles byte range requests.

Answer (score 0):

Change the user agent:

```sh
$ curl -a "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36" URL_HERE
```