# How to stream a media file using PHP?

Tags: php, file-io, buffering

I am trying to build an application in which i have to stream the media files (audio and video) to the browser. I am reading the file through php and send the data to browser. I am using the following code.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Content-Type: {$file->getMimetype()}");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$filename.";");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($file_content));

echo $file_content;
```

Every thing is working fine, except when i try to forward the video or audio, (I mean suppose current play location is 0:15 and it directly go to 1:25), media stops and when i press the play button again, it starts from the beginning.

I think the problem is with the buffering, but can't figure it out. Am i doing something wrong in header or something else is required.

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer Flash-streaming ;) , less filesize = faster loading..
Also easier to integrate into a website.

Comment: @Jordy AFAIK Flash does not do the streaming the server does. You still need a server side script to stream an flv otherwise you would have to wait for the entire file to load before you can view it.

Comment: folow that you can fast forward : __http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial__

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to implement the Range header, so that the client can skip to a specific position in the file. You can probably find out what goes wrong by [sniffing the request](https://web.archive.org/web/20111207023157/http://linuxonly.nl/docs/38/122_Introduction.html) the player sends.

Comment: Is it the players property to send which position to seek, I mean do i have to set te script in the player to specify the seek position and send then to the server.

Comment: the link is dead now.

Comment: But the archive works: https://web.archive.org/web/20111207023157/http://linuxonly.nl/docs/38/122_Introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

What you want is called "Content-Range requests"

Have a look here [Resumable downloads when using PHP to send the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this recently which may help you:

http://www.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/

Rather than passing the whole file through PHP (which eats up memory), you can use x-sendfile. This is an Apache module which allows you to run a PHP program, but pass control back to the web server to handle the actual file download once your code has done what it needs to do (authentication, etc).

It means that your PHP code doesn't have to worry about how the file is served; let the web server do what it's designed for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Now a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial for it, you only want the PHP section but still:
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Video-Streaming-PHP-Script-Tutorial/3/

Comment: Now a dead link.