# PHP file to load images but still cache everything?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'd like to use an htaccess file to redirect all media requests to a PHP file. The PHP file will analyse the filenames to see if they are in a list and if not, it will load the media files regularly.

I'd like to ensure everything about this works normally. As in, caching won't break. Do I need to do anything special with the PHP file?

Comment: where are you getting the error or where is the problem ? please paste some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes: you'll need to implement the caching logic (`Expires:`, `ETag:`, `Last-Modified:`, `304 Not Modified` and such), as PHP doesn't do that for you; if you're using sessions, you'll want to play (or fight) with the session cache limiter (as it tends to screw up caching by sending `no-cache` and needs to be overridden with the correct caching headers). [See this for a simple example](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Apr/23/conditionalGet/) - it is older but still functional.

While you're at it, implementing `206 Partial Content` [would also be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file) ("resumable downloads").

Answer (score 1):

Sending headers like [this example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#93377) would work.

Isn't this a problem BTW that can be partially handled by a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` & just letting Apache handle existing files? Just asking...

Comment: Yes, that simplifies things a lot: "only rewrite to a script if file doesn't exist" - you'll want to serve the same caching headers as Apache does, though (particularly the `ETag` and `Last_modified`).

Comment: Actually that isn't what I am trying to do. I need to see if an existing file is on a list of files not to serve to nonmembers.

Comment: RewriteMaps & other methods could be employed for that in Apache, but you're right it would be easier to let PHP handle things. Do close your session (`session_write_close()`) before sending big files though, otherwise the session is locked, and something like [X-Sendfile](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/) is also nice. Common practice for protected/limited files is usually to not even have them directly available, i.e.: outside the document root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how you want the browser cache to behave, and set the appropriate headers to be sent back with the results of the request.