# HTML5 video and partial range HTTP requests

Tags: html, http, video

I'm trying to modify a custom web server app to work with HTML5 video.

It serves a HTML5 page with a basic `<video>` tag and then it needs to handle the requests for actual content.

The only way I could get it to work so far is to load the entire video file into the memory and then send it back in a single response. It's not a practical option. I want to serve it piece by piece: send back, say, 100 kb, and wait for the browser to request more.

I see a request with the following headers:

```
http_version = 1.1
request_method = GET

Host = ###.###.###.###:##
User-Agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept = video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language = en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection = keep-alive
Range = bytes=0-
```

I tried to send back a partial content response:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 0-99999 / 232725251
Content-Length: 100000
```

I get a few more GET requests, as follows

```
Cache-Control = no-cache
Connection = Keep-Alive
Pragma = getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept = */*
User-Agent = NSPlayer/12.00.7601.17514 WMFSDK/12.00.7601.17514
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG = 1
Host = ###.###.###.###:##
```

(with no indication that the browser wants any specific part of the file.) No matter what I send back to the browser, the video does not play.

As stated above, the same video will play correctly if I try to send the entire 230 MB file at once in the same HTTP packet.

Is there any way to get this all working nicely through partial content requests? I'm using Firefox for testing purposes, but it needs to work with all browsers eventually.

Comment: I find it odd that you're using Firefox for testing and sending an MP4 file which Firefox doesn't support, so it should never work.

Comment: So far I tried Firefox (with H264 plugin) and IE9 on the browser side, and MP4 and WebM on the server side. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Why do you want to get partial range requests from clients? Just allow  them to ask what they want, and send it to them in most convenient way. I worked with streaming audio (requested from Chrome), and a custom server - it sent sounds in real time. I think this is default and acceptable way. If you bother about network load, use throttling down to a speed sufficient for smooth video playback.

Comment: I want partial range requests, because I'll be doing realtime transcoding, I can't have the file completely transcoded and available upon request.

Comment: Please don't forget to mention **@username** in replies ;-). I did almost the same with audio - realtime streaming with no real audio file on the server. I don't understand how is it possible to request partial content in such a case? Anyway, I think you should adhere to the way how most of useragents implement HTML5 media tags support. I did not test different browsers for this though, you may try.

Comment: @Stan and what is the way that most useragents implement HTML5 media tags? Can't find any good documentation anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know internal details about implementaion. All we have is the observable behaviour. According to html5 specification, there is no any attributes in `video` and `source` tags that could help in managing partial content delivery. So, I think this part of media-interactions are left completely to the browsers responsibility (at least at the moment). If you want control your content delivery in better degree, you should develop a custom mechanism, utilizing some server-side soft: so you can request and respond with a video with offsets and length limits.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but if it helps you can try the following "Model" that we use in our code base.

```
class Model_DownloadableFile {
private $full_path;

function __construct($full_path) {
    $this->full_path = $full_path;
}

public function get_full_path() {
    return $this->full_path;
}

// Function borrowed from (been cleaned up and modified slightly): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file/4451376#4451376
// Allows for resuming paused downloads etc
public function download_file_in_browser() {
    // Avoid sending unexpected errors to the client - we should be serving a file,
    // we don't want to corrupt the data we send
    @error_reporting(0);

    // Make sure the files exists, otherwise we are wasting our time
    if (!file_exists($this->full_path)) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        exit;
    }

    // Get the 'Range' header if one was sent
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        $range = $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']; // IIS/Some Apache versions
    } else if ($apache = apache_request_headers()) { // Try Apache again
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($apache as $header => $val) {
            $headers[strtolower($header)] = $val;
        }
        if (isset($headers['range'])) {
            $range = $headers['range'];
        } else {
            $range = false; // We can't get the header/there isn't one set
        }
    } else {
        $range = false; // We can't get the header/there isn't one set
    }

    // Get the data range requested (if any)
    $filesize = filesize($this->full_path);
    $length = $filesize;
    if ($range) {
        $partial = true;
        list($param, $range) = explode('=', $range);
        if (strtolower(trim($param)) != 'bytes') { // Bad request - range unit is not 'bytes'
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
            exit;
        }
        $range = explode(',', $range);
        $range = explode('-', $range[0]); // We only deal with the first requested range
        if (count($range) != 2) { // Bad request - 'bytes' parameter is not valid
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range[0] === '') { // First number missing, return last $range[1] bytes
            $end = $filesize - 1;
            $start = $end - intval($range[0]);
        } else if ($range[1] === '') { // Second number missing, return from byte $range[0] to end
            $start = intval($range[0]);
            $end = $filesize - 1;
        } else { // Both numbers present, return specific range
            $start = intval($range[0]);
            $end = intval($range[1]);
            if ($end >= $filesize || (!$start && (!$end || $end == ($filesize - 1)))) {
                $partial = false;
            } // Invalid range/whole file specified, return whole file
        }
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
    } else {
        $partial = false; // No range requested
    }

    // Determine the content type
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $contenttype = finfo_file($finfo, $this->full_path);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    // Send standard headers
    header("Content-Type: $contenttype");
    header("Content-Length: $length");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($this->full_path) . '"');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    // if requested, send extra headers and part of file...
    if ($partial) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$filesize");
        if (!$fp = fopen($this->full_path, 'r')) { // Error out if we can't read the file
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            exit;
        }
        if ($start) {
            fseek($fp, $start);
        }
        while ($length) { // Read in blocks of 8KB so we don't chew up memory on the server
            $read = ($length > 8192) ? 8192 : $length;
            $length -= $read;
            print(fread($fp, $read));
        }
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        readfile($this->full_path); // ...otherwise just send the whole file
    }

    // Exit here to avoid accidentally sending extra content on the end of the file
    exit;
}
}
```

You then use it like this:

```
(new Model_DownloadableFile('FULL/PATH/TO/FILE'))->download_file_in_browser();
```

It will deal with sending part of the file or the full file etc and works well for us in this and lots of other situations. Hope it helps.

Comment: The line that reads
  header("Content-Length: $filesize"); 
should actually be 
  header("Content-Length: $length"); 
as it is the total bytes delivered, not the size of the file. Chrome's video player barfs on this if not set correctly.

Comment: Good spot, I've corrected the original post. $length is only set if the $range is true, so I've made sure it is set to $filesize first and gets overwritten if $range is true.

Comment: My problem is that php delivers Content-Type: text/html even if header_remove('Conten-Type');

Comment: @B.F. it shouldn't be. How do you know that it is? If you are getting that header, do you know that it is php and not something else such as Apache or Nginx? Why do you want to remove the header in the first place? Why not just set the header you do want with the `header()` function?

Comment: @Luke Cousins Thanks for reply! I removed the default header from php.ini but a lot other things. So I dont know where the mistake was. To your script: you should answer a miss formed range request with header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable1');And if you like to give user a second chance: header('Content-Range: bytes */'.filesize($file),true);

Answer (score 4):

> I want partial range requests, because I'll be doing realtime transcoding, I can't have the file completely transcoded and available upon request.

For response which you don't know the full body content yet (you can't guess the `Content-Length`, live encoding), use chunk encoding:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/mp4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Trailer: Expires

1E; 1st chunk
...binary....data...chunk1..my
24; 2nd chunk
video..binary....data....chunk2..con
22; 3rd chunk
tent...binary....data....chunk3..a
2A; 4th chunk
nd...binary......data......chunk4...etc...
0
Expires: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT
```

Each chunk is send when it's available: when few frames are encoded or when the output buffer is full, 100kB are generated, etc.

```
22; 3rd chunk
tent...binary....data....chunk3..a
```

Where `22` give the chunk byte length in hexa (0x22 = 34 bytes),
`; 3rd chunk` is extra chunk infos (optional) and `tent...binary....data....chunk3..a` is the content of the chunk.

Then, when the encoding is finished and all chunks are sent, end by:

```
0
Expires: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT
```

Where `0` means there not more chunks, followed by zero or more trailer (allowed header fields) defined in the header (`Trailer: Expires` and `Expires: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT` are not required) to provide checksums or digital signatures, etc.

Here is the equivalent of the server's response if the file was already generated (no live encoding):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 142
Expires: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT

...binary....data...chunk1..myvideo..binary....data....chunk2..content...binary....data....chunk3..and...binary......data......chunk4...etc...
```

For more information: [Chunked transfer encoding — Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), [Trailer - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer)

Comment: I don't think the video tag supports chunked encoding(at least in Chrome).

Comment: The chunked transport encoding is required for HTTP/1.1 support. Also I tried, Chrome and Firefox play well videos using chunked transport encoding.
Safari (desktop and iOS) requires [ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) support to play videos (not required for audio). Transport encoding and ranges are not incompatible, but bytes ranges require to know in advance the byte size.
For that, you can use live streaming protocols (but require special treatment when encoding the video) like HLS or APIs like MSE.
See [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js)

Comment: Chrome makes a partial request regardless if the server supports it or not so I think chunked encoding alone without partial/ranges support is not enough to serve html5 video. If the server doesn't advertise the total length of the content(i.e provides a wildcard *) the player stops after the first partial request completes instead to request the next part so I guess that's a Chrome bug.

Comment: When you use chunked transport encoding you don't have to provide the Content-Length header (Note: "*" is an invalid value for this header). I made a test case, where the video load on Chrome, Firefox and IE (at least IE10). See https://gist.github.com/mems/b121bba11adc48dfd068bb7a8d113a8c (remove `usleep(200000)` if you want to load the video quicker)

Comment: that doesn't work on Chrome(on Mac). No video is playing if the Range header is not provided.