# Serving HTML5 video over http

Tags: html, http

This is a followup to [my old question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/13043816/html5-video-and-partial-range-http-requests), which was, I think, too specific to get an answer.

Generally speaking, how do I serve HTML5 video over http?

Assuming a 233 MB H.264 file, do I just write

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 232725251
```

and then try to push 232725251 bytes into the socket, or is there more to it?

Is this at all documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

That's it, unless the client asks for a specific range (that's defined in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-21.html).