# Way to seek HTML5 video when seekable.length = 0?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, html5-audio

When an HTML5 video/audio element is served from a source that does not support byte range requests, currently (in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox at least) the associated media element to the  tag seems to have an empty seekable TimeRanges object.

This is slightly confusing, as it does not have an empty buffered TimeRanges object: there is data buffered but it is not seekable.  Attempting to set currentTime to a value in the buffered range fails silently: the currentTime does not change and no error is thrown.

This is counter to most sources I've read, which suggest that buffered TimeRanges will always be included in seekable TimeRanges.  This is how I'd imagine things would work, since if the data is buffered locally there's no reason not to be able to seek inside of it.

I can not find a way to seek inside such a video at all, even to reset the current play time to 0.  Is there something I'm missing, or is this functionality just currently broken?  Is it dependent on some aspect of the video type?

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043816/html5-video-and-partial-range-http-requests

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately I have no control over the server-side.  I'm just interested in my library having an appropriate client-side response to whatever the server is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Preloader needed.

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  video.src = url;
  video.onloadeddata = resolve;
  video.onerror = reject;
});
```