# PHP/HTML Can't control video time when reading file from a readfile() php code

Tags: php, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I wanted to secure the way the video files are accessed from my server, so I use an .htaccess file to deny access to my files folder and a script verifying user identity then using readfile() to send the file to the browser.
There is the problem: when you use  with the controls attribute, you can 'move' into the video, going to the end, the middle..., but when I'm reading my video from the load_file.php, each time I click on the timeline, the cursor gets back to the current time.

Here are my files :

load_file.php (pretty simple):

```
<?php

require_once "check_user.php";

$path= 'files/'.$_GET["path"].".mp4";

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));
header("Expires: -1");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
readfile($path);

?>
```

my html page:

```
<video controls autoplay width="1080" height="720">
  <source src="load_file.php?code=XXX&path=[path_to_file_without_extension]" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser doesn't support mp4 video files, please try with a different one.
</video>
```

Is there any way to correct this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: There is a major security bug here: `$path= 'files/'.$_GET["path"].".mp4";` What if path is something like "../../../../etc/passwd"? or if safemode is enabled, the script can still be used to access arbitrary files from your account, including htaccess, htpasswd, etc.

Comment: ..ok, you can only access mp4 files. but still..

Comment: this is really not how you should do access control

Answer (score 0):

The player must be able to access your video file at any position, not just retrieve the complete file from the beginning, which is what you currently implement in your php code.

HTTP method for accessing portion of the file is "range requests", described here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Example PHP implementation for video playback can be found in the answer for this question: 
[HTML5 video and partial range HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043816/html5-video-and-partial-range-http-requests)