# php - why generated download link doesn't show file size and isn't resumable?

Tags: php, download

I use below code to generate download link for my filesm but the generated download links aren't resumable. Also, they aren't showing file size while downloading:

```
//set_time_limit(0);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: filename=file.zip");

$ch = curl_init("http://dl.otherserver.com/file.zip");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);        
exit();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Content-Length header is required if you want the size to show. Resuming requires supporting the Range header.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file

Answer (score 1):

Because the client doesn't know about the filesize yet. You need to send the `Content-Length` header.

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($myFile));
```

Don't know much about resuming file uploads though.

Comment: I do this but it doesn't solve my problem,  file size dosen't show yet.