# Serving large mp4 files with PHP for web flash video player

Tags: php

I could not find any solution anywhere.

I have a file which outputs an mp4 file for flash player like this:

`^^^/stream/NtPXRMmGjJd47423`

And I have a code for this /stream as this:

```
^^^
$file = str_replace('/','\\',DOC_ROOT_STREAM."/".$path);

header('Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Sep 2010 02:00:02 GMT');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');

readfile($file);
exit;
```

This works for small files, but does not work for large files.

I checked and URL is correct.

I tried changing `memory limit` and `time limit` but it does not help.

P.S. I cannot use Apache modules like `xsendfile`, etc.

I need a solution to `readfile()` so that it would not start loading a file in memory and then sending it to flash to read it once again and then start streaming.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$handle = fopen($file, "rb");
while (!feof($handle)) {
  echo fread($handle, 32 * 1024);
}
fclose($handle);
```

`readfile()` will attempt to load the entire contents of the file into memory. You can read a small chunk at a time with `fread()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can cause issues with large files being served by PHP is that browsers tend to only download one part of the file and then go back for more later, to save having to download everything at once when it may not even need it, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4451376/1951649 - this will let your php application handle those requests