# php headers instant download videos

Tags: php

I am trying to make a php script when you load on to that page it downloads a video. However since i do not know anything about headers it seems i can't figure it out so please explain why it works and how header works. I am trying to make the browser download video files.Can someone also explaain the headers and what they do please.

Here is my failing code:

```
<?php 
//Outputing video name
    $file_name = $_POST['FileToD'];
//outputting video extension e.g video/mp4
    $file_ext= $_POST['FileExt'];
//where the file is kept
    $file_path = 'mysever.myadress.com/media/movies/' . $file_name;
    header('Content-Type:'.$file_ext);
    header('Content-Length:' . filesize($file_path));
    header('Content-Description: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
    readfile($file_path);
?>
```

Comment: You didn't say *how* your code fails, but here's a hint how to make it work: remove ALL and every bit of HTML you have and just keep the part between `<?php` and `?>` and re-run your code.

Comment: please show output of `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17373657/1273830

Comment: Check out server logs and/or on php error_reporting to include show notices/warnings. So any problem can be shown.

Comment: There are no errors to show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you want to output a video, then don't start by outputting HTML and then switch to video data as part of the same file. (You can't set response headers after you've started outputting data anyway). **Remove everything before `<?php` and after `?>`**
2. `$file_url` should be the path, on the server's file system, to the file you want to make available. It shouldn't be a URL (unless you want a really inefficient approach or need to proxy from a different server), and if it is a URL then it needs to start with the scheme (e.g. `http://`).
3. The content-type needs to be the actual content type of the video (e.g. `video/mp4`), not a file extension (and it doesn't make sense for it to be provided by the user).

---

You also need to sanitise the user data. At present (if the errors described above were fixed) then anybody could request any file that exists on the server.

Comment: Sorry its not a url its a path my variable is wrongly named sorry about that. It has know been fixed.

Comment: File_Ext means file extension if iwas to echo this it would say video/mp4 or video/avi etc...