# Is there a way to know if my user has finished a download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

For a project, I'll need to know if my user has finished to download a file to delete it on my remote server. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Is this for S3 or EC2?

Comment: Both. A file stored in my EC2 server or on S3.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of doing this, some more efficient than others, but here is what I've come up with.

**Download through your application**

If your application is downloading/passing the file through to the user you can trigger a function at the end of the stream to delete the file.

**S3 Bucket Access Logging**

S3 has access server logs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) that log information for each request. Depending on how your application is structured, you may be able to process these to see what's been accessed.

*There may be up to a 30-60 minute delay in log availability*

**Other Options**

There are some other options, though perhaps not ideal (without knowing the specifics of your application I don't know whether these are acceptable).

- Use Object Expiration (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html)
- Related SO question (PHP instead of ROR, but the concepts should apply) [Resumable downloads when using PHP to send the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file)