# HTML5 video not playing on certain ipads when SCORM packaged

Tags: ios, html, ipad, video, scorm

Would anyone know why html5 video would not work only when run from an LMS(Learning management system) on an IPad?

This seems to be device specific.

I've tested 5 ipads, 3 have worked and 2 haven't. I've used two different models, the air and the model before the air(has the lightning port). The version of the OS has varied, but Ive had 7.1.2 produce different results, both of which were the air model.

I've tested 2 LMS systems and the devices that don't work, don't work on both LMSs.

I don't believe the content is at fault. I get the same results when using completely different tools to embed the video. I'm currently using the projector html5 player(hand coding). But this content doesn't work when I use Lectora to publish it. Also I've tested multiple videos encoded from multiple sources, same thing happens...

What really has me stumped is the fact I CAN play the videos on a normal webserver on these devices.

Any suggestions would be great. Even somewhere to start looking with IPad settings. I'm at a loss?

Thanks in advance!

Androo

Oh, could embedded frames affect my results? LMS/SCORM players almost always run content through them.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can access the mime types supported by the LMS.  Most likely the server is having issues with newer video formats.  Hopefully if you don't have direct access, you can open a support ticket.  Just let them know what movie types you support.
Pretty common issue on legacy systems.

If thats not it, maybe sample your failover  code for each browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem and solved it. This can happen either because the Web server has to send the proper Mime type (video/mp4) as @Mark suggested, but also because the web server should stream the video. There are specific ways to stream the video to the client:

If you're serving the file with PHP, then have a look at [Resumable downloads when using PHP to send the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file), this has worked for me. If you're serving the file from apache directly, have a look at the xsendfile module for apache, which is great at serving files of any kind, and will also solve this problem.