# PHP Curl direct Download/Stream Partial Content

Tags: php, curl, nginx, download

I want to send/stream Files from an other Website/Webadress directly to the user, without storing the Files on my Server. The Files are Archives about 100MB to 1GB

The download with one thread works fine. Here is my Code:

```
$ch5 = curl_init();
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file
    preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);
    $offset = intval($matches[1]);
    $end = $matches[2] || $matches[2] === '0' ? intval($matches[2]) : $size - 1;
    curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_RANGE, "$offset-$end");
}
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_URL, $direct_link);
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3550); 
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15); 
curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'readHeader');
curl_exec($ch5);
$dlsize = curl_getinfo($ch5,CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD );
$time = curl_getinfo($ch5,CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
curl_close($ch5);

function readHeader($ch, $header) // Send header from the Downloaded file to the User
{
    header($header);
    return strlen($header);
}
```

The problem is that PHP Download the complete file if the request contains an Range like "Range: bytes=0-" and sending it to the user. But the User download much slower(Cause slower download speed) then downloading it to my Server, but if the file is completely downloaded, the file isn't available on the external Server.
And when the Client make an Range Request for the second half or something else the Request goes to the external Server and the file isn't available, cause it is already completely downloaded by the first request, but I cant access the Data or is there a way to get these Data, without saving them on my disk?

I want to save Bandwidth an want to give users the possibility to make Range Requests. 
So PHP should only download the amount the user really want to download or make a direct connection between the external Server and User.

Actually I am using nginx/1.6.2 and PHP 5.5.20-1 on Ubuntu 12.04.5

Comment: PHP is not what you want to use for this.  Look into using Squid http://www.squid-cache.org/

Comment: The Problem is, that the User should not see the original URL and I need PHP to store the Downloaded size, cause every User has a limited download contingent.
Or is there the possibility to user Squid in PHP

Comment: Squid has these features.

Comment: I solved my problem by using nginx with X-Sendfile. More Information here: http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using nginx with X-Sendfile/X-Accel-Redirect . More Information here: wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile