# PHP download resume in Chrome HTTP RANGE not working

Tags: php, google-chrome, download, resume

I'm using the following code, I adapted: http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php#84115 to my code to allow download resume, it works great on firefox but doesn't work at all in chrome. If I try in chrome, the file is downloading, I pause it, wait a few minutes, but then when I resume it the download finishes instantly and the file is corrupted.

Any idea why?

```
function dl_file_resumable($file, $is_resume=TRUE)
{
    //First, see if the file exists
    if (!is_file($file))
    {
        die("<b>404 File not found!</b>");
    }

    //Gather relevent info about file
    $size = filesize($file);
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($file);

    //workaround for IE filename bug with multiple periods / multiple dots in filename
    //that adds square brackets to filename - eg. setup.abc.exe becomes setup[1].abc.exe
    $filename = (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')) ?
                  preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $fileinfo['basename'], substr_count($fileinfo['basename'], '.') - 1) :
                  $fileinfo['basename'];

    $file_extension = strtolower($path_info['extension']);

    $ctype='application/octet-stream';

    //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
    if($is_resume && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);

        if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
        {
            //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
            //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
            list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $range = '';
    }

    //figure out download piece from range (if set)
    list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

    //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
    //also check for invalid ranges.
    $seek_end = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($size - 1));
    $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

    //add headers if resumable
    if ($is_resume)
    {
        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        }

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$size);
    }

    //headers for IE Bugs (is this necessary?)
    //header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");   
    //header("Pragma: public");

    header('Content-Type: ' . $ctype);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));

    //open the file
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    //seek to start of missing part
    fseek($fp, $seek_start);

    //start buffered download
    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        //reset time limit for big files
        set_time_limit(0);
        print(fread($fp, 1024*8));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    }

    fclose($fp);
    exit;
}

dl_file_resumable('/home/var/www/app/back/media/ready/5a58hGuRFR.tar');
```

Comment: Ain't [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file) enough examples of how to do this?

Comment: You have not included the full script, are you ending the script with a `?>` by any chance?

Comment: Also, what web server software are you using?

Comment: @Bonner Yeah my script is ending with ?> I'm running apache as webserver on a debian 7

Comment: Remove the ?> from the end of the script and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I did not tried execute your code, but it looks like there is some mess with switch statement:

1. It does not have any meaning - if $ext is set at all, it will fall into one and only default section
2. It has wrong syntax - after default should be `:`
3. It has variable `$new_name` which isn't set anywhere

In the end, having these errors in reply, different browsers will handle them differently.

Comment: Even more - I see no sense in the switch statement whatsoever.

Comment: Hi, I updated my code with the full function and some modifications, I removed the switch part for content type because I want to force download, so I'm always using "application/octet-stream".

Comment: @Mokkun, so it means it works for you? I tried with some ~180MB zip file, it works for me on chrome 43.0.2357.124 m. + I added `usleep(100);` at end of `while(!feof($fp))` cycle to simulate network speed. It works also on Firefox, Opera. IE does not allow to stop (button disabled), but Safari for windows after stop resumes download from beginning.

Comment: @Pilskalns for me it works on Firefox (paused the download for an hour and resumed it) but it doesn't on Chrome, when I resume the download after ~30min it says the download is finished and the file get corrupted (it can't resume where it stopped). As for network speed you could have just changed the print(fread($fp, 1024*8)); part