# How to download LARGE files using AWS getObject and Range?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download the large files from the AWS S3 with the getObject method. But for large files the page gets down. How i can use the range to download the file completely in parts?

```
function DownloadContent($keyName) {
    $store = array();
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/s3Config.php');

    if (!$this->s3Client) {
        $this->s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
                    'key' => $store['s3']['key'],
                    'secret' => $store['s3']['secret']
        ));
    }

    foreach ($keyName as $key => $row) {
        $varFileName = explode('/', $row);
        $bucket = 'my-bucket-name';
        $result = $this->s3Client->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $row
        ));

        header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$varFileName[2]}\"");
        header('Expires: 0');header("X-Sendfile: $varFileName[2]");
        echo $result['Body'];
    }
}
```

Comment: What actual error are you getting? Are you running out of memory in PHP? The files have to be loaded into PHP, taking up memory, so you need more than enough memory available to cope with them.

Comment: The page is getting the error ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE, i think that the large files response is going through. I want to use the range attribute for the concurrent downloads.

Comment: Is there anything in your PHP Error logs?

Comment: When you talk about "large" you can't be completely vague like this. The last time I had a "large file problem" all the answers referenced sizes of 10 to 100 MB, whereas I was looking at 300 to 600 **G**B. "Large" is very relative.

Comment: my file sizes are also in GB's that needs to be downloaded.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's a rather old question, there doesn't seem to be an answer to it though.

- [stream_copy_to_stream()](https://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream) should help with the memory usage
- the stream is seekable, setting the headers as described in [Resumable downloads when using PHP to send the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file) should work just fine

```
$bucket_name = 'my-bucket';
$object_key = 'object-key';

// initialize the S3 client

$client = new S3Client(...);

// register the stream

$client->registerStreamWrapper();

// get the file size

$file_size = filesize('s3://'.$bucket_name.'/'.$object_key);

// get the meta data

$meta_data = $client->headObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
    'Key' => $object_key
]);

// get the offset & length

$offset = 0;
$length = $file_size;
$partial_content = false;

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    // the first 500 bytes: bytes=0-499
    // the second 500 bytes: bytes=500-999
    // all bytes except for the first 500 until the end of document: bytes=500-
    // the last 500 bytes of the document: bytes=-500

    preg_match('{bytes=(\d+)?-(\d+)?(,)?}i', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);

    if(empty($matches[3])) {
        $partial_content = true;
        $offset = (!empty($matches[1])) ? intval($matches[1]) : 0;
        $length = (!empty($matches[2])) ? intval($matches[2]) : $file_size;
        $length -= $offset;
    }
}

// set the headers for partial content

if($partial_content === true) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + $length - 1) . '/' . $file_size);
}

// set the regular HTTP headers

header('Content-Type: '.$meta_data['ContentType']);
header('Content-Length: '.$file_size);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($object_key).'"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

// open a S3 stream to the file

$s3file = fopen('s3://'.$bucket_name.'/'.$object_key, 'rb');

if(!$s3file) {
    throw new Exception('Error opening S§ stream for reading!');
}

// open an output stream

$out = fopen('php://output', 'wb');

// copy data from the S3 stream to the output stream

fseek($s3file, $offset);
stream_copy_to_stream($s3file, $out, $length);

// close the streams

fclose($out);
fclose($s3file);
```

Just FYI: I've excluded the multirange options ...