# best header setup for send data to user

Tags: php

I'm using following php code to send zip(and rar) files to user for download,

but it doesn't display file size (in idm) and finish time and i'm not able to stop and resume it and it just download file by 1 port and totally its awful.

what do you suggest me to do ?

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type:application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma:public');
header('Content-Length:'.filesize($file_adress));
readfile($file_adress);
exit;
```

Comment: This problem is not only your php codes !  Did you check the server config ?

Comment: my server config is ok i think , can web.config cuse it ??

Comment: Your server linux or windows ?

Comment: my server is windows server 2012 ! IIS 7

Comment: Check out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file#157352