# How to protect files by query key?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to protect files by query key in PHP. For example:

```
http://example.com/file.mp4?key=sdkjhslkdjvkjbvs
```

If the query key is in the database, let to download and read file if not forward location.

How can I do this?

Comment: Execute a query, check returned result.

Comment: where can i get this query? in php $_GET['key'] but in .mp4 file?

Comment: this is a mp4 file! how can i get this query in server?

Comment: Create rewrite rule

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: Hey, to make this happen you need some logic on the server to accept the url, rewrite it to send it to the handler file and for that handler file to run a query and test the key against your expected value and return either a fail or to start the stream of data for the file. It's much too vast of a topic to cover in a single SO answer. You should consider taking the concept and breaking it into much smaller problems so you can ask specific questions about each area you are not able to make work.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect .mp4 to .php (without url changing). Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).mp4?key=(.*)$  /video/test.php?key=$2&file=$1
```

After this you can catch $_GET['key'] and check your database - if ok you can throw you file for downloading

```
if(file_exists($file_link)){
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=/".$file_link);
    echo readfile($file_link);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! But readfile ram occupies a lot and not resumable

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file